# Making a Drop Down list in Excel?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have an excel sheet that I need to pull information from. I have a name column that I want to be selectable in a drop down menu, but when it is selected I need it to bring up the rest of it's row of information that is associated with it. I am also trying to format the information in a different way than just in a straight row across.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a new sheet and list all variations
2. Select variations and add a name to selected range
3. In the cell where you want to see the dropdown select validation from the data tab
4. Select LIST and use your named range as a reference

also check here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/

Comment: Thanks! Additionally I'm trying to get a whole bunch of extra information to pop up when the piece of data is selected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask a new question; it's another topic